# How to get libutils.so

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gsl

I have been given some legacy C++ code that I am trying to compile and run on Ubuntu 12.04. One of the lines in the makefile attempts to build the code with the "-lutils" flag, and when I run the makefile I get the following message:

```
"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lutils"
```

By the way, the code relies on the GSL library, which I do have installed. I know that the code is building on another Ubuntu machine in my office, but I want to know why it is not building mine. I have tried finding libutils.so on the interntet and downloading it but I can't find a download link anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you are right, libutils seems to be part of GSL --
just install complete GSL package system-wide to let your build system find libutils